# Function templates in c++?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, dynamic-memory-allocation, template-function

For school, I have an assignment to create a function template and use the users input for dynamic memory. My code is not working, but my teacher says it is correct and it is just my compiler that does not work. This is the error I get from the compiler:

> error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
>            key = array[I];

I use the compiler MinGW64. Is there anyone with the same problem who has a solution?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

template <class S>  
void sortArray(S &array, int n);

template <class R>
void reverseArray(R &array, int n);

template <class P>
void printArray(P array, int n);

int main() {
    int n1, n2, i;

    srand(time(0));

    cout << "insert how many numbers:";
    cin >> n1;
    int *nums = new int[n1];
    if(nums == 0){
        cout << "No memory allocated";
        exit(1);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n1; i++){
        nums[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
    }
    printArray(nums, n1);
    sortArray(nums, n1);
    printArray(nums, n1);
    reverseArray(nums, n1);
    printArray(nums, n1);
    delete []nums;

    cout << "insert how many characters:";
    cin >> n2;
    char *nums2 = new char[n2];
    if(nums2 == 0){
        cout << "No memory allocated";
        exit(1);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n2; i++){
        nums2[i] =  rand() % 25 + 97; // rand() % 93 + 33
    }
    printArray(nums2, n2);
    sortArray(nums2, n2);
    printArray(nums2, n2);
    reverseArray(nums2, n2);
    printArray(nums2, n2);
    delete []nums2;

    return 0;
}

template <class S>
void sortArray(S &array, int n){
    int i, j;
    S key;
    for(i = 1; i < n; i++){
        key = array[i];
        for(j = i-1; (j>=0) && (array[j] > key); j--){
             array[j+1] = array[j];
        }
        array[j+1] = key;
    }
}

template <class R>
void reverseArray(R &array, int n){
    int start = 0, end = n-1;
    R temp;
    while(start < end){
        temp = array[start];
        array[start] = array[end];
        array[end] = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}

template <class P>
void printArray(P array, int n){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
         cout << "[" <<i << "] => " << array[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `new` and raw pointers / arrays at all?

Comment: You have to decide what `S` is in `sortArray`. If it's the type of element in your container then `S & array` is not correct. If `S` is your container type then `S keyl` is not right.

Comment: We have to use new because the teacher told is. It is part of the assigmnent. The array has to be every type as possible and that is why key has to be the same type as the array. Otherwise you can loose data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is definitely not wrong.

There is some miscommunication.

When you declare

```
template <class S>  
void sortArray(S &array, int n);
```

and ust it as

```
sortArray(nums, n1);
```

`S` is deduced as `int*` given the definition of `nums` in your posted code. Hence, you may not use

```
S key;
for(i = 1; i < n; i++){
    key = array[i];
```

since `key` is of type `int*` while `array[i]` is of type `int`.

You can fix the problem by using one of the following two options.

1. Change the function declaration to

   ```
   template <class S>  
   void sortArray(S* array, int n);
   ```
2. Change the type of `key`.

   ```
   typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*array)>::type key;
   ```

   or let the compiler deduce it using `auto`.

   ```
   auto key = array[0];
   ```

   The downside of using the second method is that the program will have undefined behavior if `array` is empty.

You'll have to change `reverseArray` similarly.

Comment: It is correct but misleading to say that `S` is deduced as `int*`. It is simply a pointer because `sortArray` is called with a pointer. Had `nums` of `sortArray(nums, n1);` been an array, so S would have been an array type. Someone reading your answer may get the impression that when passing an array to `sortArray` it decays to a pointer, which is not the case since this is a reference parameter.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler, In the posted code, `nums` is a `int*`. I took the liberty of using that information.

Comment: Yes, this is what I wrote in my comment. I also wrote that the wording may confuse someone. I think that you should also write that the caller passes a pointer, which is not strictly required, but it makes things clearer

Comment: @MichaelVeksler, I updated the answer just a bit to clarify that point. Thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the information. My teacher wouldn't help me because he was convinced it was my compiler. 
So all I had to do was chancing my function declaration to `void sortArray(S *array, int n);` and now it works perfectly.